# A "messy sounding" word for tangled

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find a good way to describe a string that's really tangled. I like the word cacophonous because it sounds cacophonous. However, cacophonous points to sound. The other words, messy, gnarled, knotty, don't really have that punch to it. What's a word that means "tangled" that delivers a sound that cacophonous does, but doesn't relate to sound at all?

The worst thing about the holidays is having to deal with the _________ Christmas lights.

Comment: Why don't you like **tangled**? BTW **gnarled** does not describe string, but trees, hands etc.

Comment: If by "tangled" you mean "together", try one of [the `kl-`words.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf)

Comment: Well, there's "convoluted", which is pretty convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of **snarled**, which has two meanings. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/snarl) has

> **snarl¹**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> 1 (of an animal such as a dog) Make an aggressive growl with bared teeth.
> *They snarled and bared their teeth in a predatory way.*

and also

> **snarl²**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> 1 (snarl something up) Entangle something.
> *the trailing lead got snarled up in a bramble bush*

Does this word have enough cacophony for you? Unfortunately someone who says

> The worst thing about the holidays is having to deal with the snarled Christmas lights.

sounds like a bit of a Scrooge.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very obscure word, but [thrackled](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thrackle) might work.

[This website](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/%7Emohar/Problems/THRACKLE.HTM) describes how John Conway, a mathematician, heard the word and used it for a mathematical concept:

> Conway says "When I was a teenager, on holiday with my parents in Scotland, we once stopped to ask directions of a man who was fishing by the side of a lake. He happened to mention that his line was thrackled. I'd previously called this kind of drawing a tangle, but since I'd just found a knot-theoretical use for that term, I changed this to thrackle. Several people have told me that they've searched in vain for this word in dialect dictionaries, but since I quizzed the fisherman about it, I'm sure I didn't mishear it; he really did use it."

Answer (score 0):

[tortuous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tortuous)

> with many turns and changes of direction; not direct or simple:

It is, to be sure, a somewhat obscure word.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit "the"

Taffled

Jumbled

Entwined

A mat of

A Gordian knot of (Historical reference)